# Taylor's Theorem Question: finding $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sin x)^{70}}{1-\cos (x^{105})}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I am trying to calculate $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(x-\sin x)^{70}}{1-\cos (x^{105})}$$

Here is my attempt: $ $
write $\cos$ and $\sin$ as Taylor series, and plug back into the original expression yields:$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{(x^3/3!-x^5/5!+x^7/7!-...)^{70}}{x^{210}/2!-x^{420}/4!+x^{630}/6!-...}$$

And here is where I feel uncertain. I wanted to expand the numerator, in which the first term would be $x^{210}/3!$, and then taking the limit as $x$ approaches $0$, since $x$ is close to $0$, its absolute value is certainly less than $1$, so irrelevant terms can be ignored and leaving the expression to become $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{210}/6^{70}}{x^{210}/2}$$ 
and the limit would be $\frac{2}{6^{70}}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good work, the answer is correct. You might have felt greater comfort by "taking out" a common factor of $x^3/6$ on top before raising to the $70$-th power, and taking out a common factor of $x^{210}/2$ in the denominator. Then you get cancellation, and $\frac{2}{6^{70}}$ times an expression in which lead coefficient in numerator and denominator is $1$. The behaviour as $x\to 0$ is then clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is OK. We have, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(x-\sin x)^{70}}{1-\cos x^{105}}&=\frac{(x^3/3!+O(x^5))^{70}}{x^{210}/2!+O(x^{420})}\\\\
&=\frac{x^{210}/6^{70}(1+O(x^2))^{70}}{x^{210}/2+O(x^{420})}
\\\\&=\frac{x^{210}/6^{70}(1+O(x^2))}{x^{210}/2+O(x^{420})}
\\\\&\to\frac{2}{6^{70}}
\end{align}
$$